# Windows 10 Safe Mode, still BSODs with WDF_VIOLATION

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I switched my M2.SSD from a Dell XPS 9570 with a dedicated graphics card to a Dell XPS 9360. Installed is Windows 10 Pro x64 with BitLocker enabled.

Now, when starting up after typing my recovery key, I get a WDF_VIOLATION BSOD. Naturally I tried to safe-boot into Windows using a Windows installation media. Problem: even when selecting safe mode, it still fails with the same BSOD.

Using the command prompt of the installation media, I can perfectly browse through all BitLocker encrypted sections. So it must not be a hard drive problem.

I already tried the automatic startup repair functionality from the recovery media. It says "automatic repair is not possible".

What can I do in this case?

Update: I was able to unprotected the device using the command line from a troubleshoot bootable USB. Still, the error persists.

I used the following command to unprotect the system drive:

manage-bde -protectors -disable C: -rp "key here"

Now I can boot into the troubleshoot command line from the USB stick without entering the recovery key and can see all my volumes using diskpart and I can even browse all my files on the C: partition.

Trying to disable encryption fully does not seem to work, though:

manage-bde -off C:

Results in:

ERROR: An error occurred (code 0x80073bc3):
The requested system device cannot be found.

Which is totally strange since just seconds before it was happy to unprotect the same drive.

manage-bde -status C:

Results in saying the drive is unlocked as well as unprotected.

Comment: Read this in its entirety....https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/hp-pcs-getting-wdf-violation-bsod-after-installing-windows-10-updates/

Comment: Hey, I do have a Dell computer though. I don't see any hint in this article how I should rescue my installation. The driver mentioned there is not installed on my system.

Comment: You did not read very carefully!  "According to a post to the Microsoft forums, a support agent allegedly told a caller that this product is also affecting other systems such as Dell and that they have paused the update while they investigate the issue."

Comment: I read this sentence. Still, the mentioned driver is not installed on my system and there is no solution provided. Am I missing something from this article which is not obvious?

Comment: "Unfortunately, some BC users are reporting that they are receiving this BSOD crash and do not have the HpqKbFiltr.sys driver on their computer" Evidently there is no fix for Dell PC's, what you can try is to remove  the KB4462919  update, see if the problem is solved now.

Comment: For analysis, better post a screenshot of the BSOD, and if possible the `.dmp` file from `C:\Windows\Minidump`. (For addressing a person include his name in the comment like `@harrymc`).

Comment: That specific update is not installed. I used the command dism /Image:C:\ /get-packages to check.

Comment: @harrymc The BSOD gives no further information other than WDF_VIOLATION. It just refers to https://www.windows.com/stopcode, but this does not bring me any further. There is no error code. Also, the minidump folder is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was one of these drivers. My last act before I would be forced reinstalling Windows was to just remove all drivers which sounded unnecessary for the system bootup. And guess what, it solved the problem. I did this with the command prompt from a bootable USB stick and used the command:

```
Dism /Image:C:\ /Remove-Driver:<name>
```

The list of drivers can be received with

```
Dism /Image:C\ /Get-Drivers
```

I don't know which of these drivers was the faulty one. After being able to go into Windows, I ran Windows Update and it installed all now-missing drivers automatically.

My system seems to be in a perfect and healthy state. Apparently, the issue was not related to BitLocker.

For anybody interested, here's the list of drivers I uninstalled:

```
Published Name : oem0.inf
Original File Name : prnms009.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : Printer
Provider Name : Microsoft
Date : 6/21/2006
Version : 10.0.17763.1

Published Name : oem13.inf
Original File Name : intcaudiobus.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : System
Provider Name : Intel(R) Corporation
Date : 11/4/2016
Version : 9.21.0.1680

Published Name : oem18.inf
Original File Name : oemsetup.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : Printer
Provider Name : Ricoh
Date : 12/9/2015
Version : 1.9.0.0

Published Name : oem19.inf
Original File Name : hpvyt12.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : Printer
Provider Name : HP
Date : 4/16/2013
Version : 12.28.0.2027

Published Name : oem20.inf
Original File Name : hpwia_oj4630.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : Image
Provider Name : Hewlett-Packard
Date : 4/16/2013
Version : 31.0.1150.42326

Published Name : oem21.inf
Original File Name : hpoj4630fax.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : Printer
Provider Name : HP
Date : 11/11/2013
Version : 32.0.110.46548

Published Name : oem22.inf
Original File Name : hpreststub.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : USB
Provider Name : Hewlett-Packard
Date : 4/16/2013
Version : 31.0.1150.42326

Published Name : oem23.inf
Original File Name : prnms006.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : Printer
Provider Name : Microsoft
Date : 11/29/2016
Version : 16.0.7629.4000

Published Name : oem24.inf
Original File Name : nvdm.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : Display
Provider Name : NVIDIA
Date : 5/22/2018
Version : 24.21.13.9793

Published Name : oem25.inf
Original File Name : nvhda.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : MEDIA
Provider Name : NVIDIA Corporation
Date : 5/22/2018
Version : 1.3.37.4

Published Name : oem29.inf
Original File Name : intcaudiobus.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : System
Provider Name : Intel(R) Corporation
Date : 3/27/2018
Version : 10.23.0.1520

Published Name : oem3.inf
Original File Name : ibtusb.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : Bluetooth
Provider Name : Intel Corporation
Date : 10/8/2018
Version : 20.90.1.1

Published Name : oem37.inf
Original File Name : hdx_dellcsmbext_waves.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : Extension
Provider Name : Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Date : 5/29/2018
Version : 6.0.1.8454

Published Name : oem38.inf
Original File Name : dellaudioextwaves.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : Extension
Provider Name : Dell
Date : 5/30/2018
Version : 1.3.2.178

Published Name : oem39.inf
Original File Name : wavesapo75de.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : SoftwareComponent
Provider Name : Waves
Date : 5/15/2018
Version : 3.2.0.76

Published Name : oem4.inf
Original File Name : intcdaud.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : MEDIA
Provider Name : Intel(R) Corporation
Date : 3/22/2018
Version : 10.25.0.4

Published Name : oem44.inf
Original File Name : lwcusb.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : Image
Provider Name : Logitech
Date : 10/24/2018
Version : 1.3.89.0

Published Name : oem45.inf
Original File Name : helloface.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : Biometric
Provider Name : Windows Hello Face
Date : 6/1/2018
Version : 10.0.17763.168

Published Name : oem47.inf
Original File Name : intcdaud.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : MEDIA
Provider Name : Intel(R) Corporation
Date : 9/4/2018
Version : 10.26.0.1

Published Name : oem48.inf
Original File Name : intcdaudsgpcoffext.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : Extension
Provider Name : Intel Corporation
Date : 11/18/2018
Version : 25.20.100.6323

Published Name : oem9.inf
Original File Name : intcdaud.inf
Inbox : No
Class Name : MEDIA
Provider Name : Intel(R) Corporation
Date : 12/6/2017
Version : 10.24.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error as I was stumbling around trying to fix my wife's Dell XPS 13 after a failed update.

ERROR: An error occurred (code 0x80073bc3):
The requested system device cannot be found

I kept trying to figure out WHY IT COULD NOT BE FOUND. I mean, I’m working on the device now, right? I’m making changes to it, and you’re acknowledging that I’ve made changes to it, but also, it’s not found? Huh?

The insight was when I traced it back to the specific error code in the Microsoft documentation. (Other web posts I found mentioning this error code had never had the difficulty I had resolving it.)

Here’s what it said on the [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolution-procedures) page (emphasis mine):

> 0x80073BC3 - 0x20009 0x80070002 - 0x20009 0x80073B92 - 0x20009    These
> errors occur during partition analysis and validation, **and can be
> caused by the presence of multiple system partitions.** For example,
> , if you installed a new system drive but left the previous system drive,
> connected, this can cause a conflict. To resolve the errors,
> disconnect or temporarily disable drives that contain the unused
> system partition. You can reconnect the drive after the upgrade has
> completed. Alternatively, you can delete the unused system
> partition.    The requested system device cannot be found, there is a
> sharing violation, or there are multiple devices matching the
> identification criteria.

**I realized that the problem might not be that it couldn’t FIND a partition. It was that it found MORE THAN ONE system/boot partition.**

I remembered early on in this multi-day process that in following some fix I had found on the interwebs, I had marked a partition on a 2nd disk as ACTIVE before I knew what the hell I was doing.

I went into diskpart, marked it as INACTIVE, and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal for a disk secured with bitlocker.

Most people will put the drive back in the old machine, then remove bitlocker.
move the disk to the new machine then reinstall bitlocker.  (It has to do with the particular TPM in each device.)

Yes I am aware that you can move the disk without doing that. But the procedure is often too complicated for most people, so i'm not going to bother with it here. Its much easier to uninstall, move, reinstall.

Comment: Sadly, the old machine does not belong to me anymore. I can't do it. I would totally love to through the hassle if there's a solution in sight.

Comment: For anybody else trying to find a solution: it was apparently not related to BitLocker. Please see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The Microsoft article
[BitLocker Deployment and Administration FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-deployment-and-administration-faq)
says:

> **Can I access my BitLocker-protected drive if I insert the hard disk into a different computer?**
>
> Yes, if the drive is a data drive, you can unlock it from the
>   BitLocker Drive Encryption Control Panel item just as you would any
>   other data drive by using a password or smart card. If the data drive
>   was configured for automatic unlock only, you will have to unlock it
>   by using the recovery key. The encrypted hard disk can be unlocked by
>   a data recovery agent (if one was configured) or it can be unlocked by
>   using the recovery key.

The answer is then that you cannot boot from the disk in another computer
than the original one,
but you may unlock the disk while booting from another disk.

I suggest then to either put the disk in another computer for unlocking it
and then undoing the BitLocker encryption before returning it to the
Dell XPS 9360 computer.
Perhaps booting from a Windows boot USB will be enough to make it work.

Comment: This indeed sounds very convincing. I booted into command prompt from troubleshooting mode (using the recovery key) and tried disabling BitLocker using "manage-bde -off C:". It says: "An error occurred (code 0x80073bc3): The requested system device cannot be found".  The drive I am trying to get to boot obviously was not only a data drive but one equipped with the whole system.

Comment: It's not a boot disk if it's not booted from, but it seems that booting from USB is not enough.

Comment: This means the system is lost in space? Sorry, I am a bit confused :-)

Comment: I also added an update to my original post.

Comment: It means you have to boot with another disk, where the bitlocker disk is in the same computer, but as a secondary (data) disk and is not used for the boot. You need to unencrypt the disk before using it for booting, and then you can encrypt it again. Bitlocker for the boot disk requires the same BIOS (meaning computer) on which it was encrypted in order to boot. In any case, I advise against encrypting the boot disk. You may partition the disk, if required, and encrypt the non-boot (data) partition, leaving the boot partition as unencrypted.

Comment: I get that. Right now, the disk is unprotected (I used manage-bde for that). It means I should be able to boot, right? Still, it doesn't work. I have the feeling BitLocker is not the problem here. Next step for me is to enable Minidumps from the command line. Still didn't find useful info about that, though.

Comment: Let me know when more data is available. Add in the post the command you used for unlocking it. If I understand right, the boot CD/USB method does work.

Comment: I updated my post. Attaching the disk to another computer is currently not possible since all my laptops only have one M2 slot.

Comment: If you boot from USB into command and do not use manage-bde, is the disk visible and accessible?

Comment: Yes. I am even able to modify/create new files using the copy con command on my C:partition. I am trying to get more information but I am currently unable to enable Minidumps, see https://superuser.com/questions/1398671/using-wmic-in-cmd-from-booted-usb-in-troubleshoot-mode

Comment: I think the disk is now unencrypted, but needs [Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Is failing. The mentioned log file (SrtTrail.txt) won't be created.

Comment: I was now able to modify the registry to enable Mimidumps. Sadly, still nothing is created. I am out of ideas.

Comment: From the fact that the boot USB succeeds but that boot from the disk does not work, I fear that you are missing a driver in your installed Windows, a driver that exists on the installation USB but that was not ever installed before. I suggest re-installing Windows to the disk. If the installation can find the existing Windows on the disk, it will only "upgrade" Windows to itself so you keep all applications and most settings. Ensure that you are using the latest Windows version for the installation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. I was able to solve the problem. If you're interested, you can read my answer. Until the end I was not able to get a memory dump. Strange!