# Using wmic in cmd from booted USB in troubleshoot mode

Tags: windows-10, bsod, wmic, recovery

I am having a [Windows installation which fails to boot (BSOD)](https://superuser.com/questions/1398551/windows-10-safe-mode-still-bsods-with-wdf-violation). Safe mode is not working, too. So I created a Windows bootable USB stick and am now in the command prompt from the troubleshoot mode.

The USB stick is mounted on X:, the non-working Windows installation is on C:. I can browse all my personal files etc, so I am sure C: is the correct drive.

To debug further, I want to enable Minidumps. The internet says the following command is the way to go:

wmic recoveros set DebugInfoType = 3

Done and it says it was successful. Still, there are no Minidumps created. Turns out when I reboot into the recovery, the DebugInfoType is changed back to 7.

When I get all properties using

wmic recovers get

it also shows all paths with X:\ instead of C:.

My suspicion is that the wmic command operates on the currently booted recovery Windows but not for the actually intended installation on C:.

How can I force wmic to operate on behalf of the C:-installation?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://superuser.com/questions/1398043/externally-enable-minidump-creation-in-windows/1398052#1398052

Comment: Thanks! I was now able to change the setting. Nevertheless, I don't get minidumps.

Comment: Did you set the page file size to >=400MB?  Details in same link.  You also have to recreate the error - it will not recreate dumps from historical bugchecks.

Comment: I set it to 1GB. I recreated the error (blue screen). Even on the blue screen page it says nothing about dumping memory. I know that from previous BSODs that a text is shown, even with a percentage counter.

Comment: @moderators: It indeed is a duplicate by the way.